# Query events from Google Calendar API v3 using Java client library?

Tags: java, google-calendar-api, client-library

v1 Calendar API client library that [my project](https://github.com/home-climate-control/dz/tree/master/dz3-master/dz3-scheduler-gcal) used for years (and which is being shut down in a couple of weeks) had a clearly defined [CalendarQuery](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/calendar/CalendarQuery), however, v3 doesn't seem to have any client library objects dedicated for this purpose.

Of course, I can use their [JSON HTTP request](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) and parse the response, but it would be a shame to do if the client library can do it.

Anyone out there found the way to provide query parameters to `list()` call?

**UPDATE (based on user32116's comments):**

So the missing piece is that `list()` and `execute()` can and need to be separated.

Actual query code will look like this:

```
Calendar.Events.List events = calendarClient.events().list(id);

events.setTimeMin(start);
events.setTimeMax(end);
events.set... // your criteria here

Events result = events.execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well they do have examples of how to query calendars and events. See here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#examples

The old API used [CalendarQuery](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/client/calendar/CalendarQuery) to query events, in the new version [Calendar.Events.List](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/calendar/Calendar.Events.List.html) is used.